# Lucene SpanQuery weak spots

Tags: performance, lucene, full-text-search, bigdata

I have a ~20GB index of documents that have words with several attributes associated with them, e.g.:

WORD: word_1 word_2 ... word_n

POS:    pos1_1:pos1_2:pos1:3 pos2 ... pos_n_1:pos_n_2

LEMMA: lemma1_1:lemma1:2:lemma1_3 lemma2 lemma_n_1:lemma_n_2

Field tokens separated by ':' are ambiguous, i.e. they correspond to the same position in the document.
An important detail of ambiguous word attributes is that, e.g., pos1_1 corresponds only to lemma1_1, not to lemma1_2 or 1_3, so one must not match word_1 when searching for pos1_1 & lemma1_3 at the same position.

I handle ambiguous tokens position with standard positionIncrement = 0, and attribute number correspondence with token payloads. Say, lemma1_1 has payload = 1, lemma1_2 - 2; pos1_1 - 1, pos1_2 - 2, and so on. And while searching for token attributes at the same position I use payload filter that checks if the payloads of all tokens matched are the same.

And that's it: SpanNearQueries run super slow on that index (10's of seconds). The majority of documents in the index matches to a regular query.
I don't know actually how SpanQueries work in-depth, but is there some inefficiency in them by design? Or is payload retrieval so expensive?
I'm just wondering if I'm missing something obvious that slows down the entire search.